# Creating objects with "new" keyword or without "new" in Java

Tags: java, reference, new-operator

Hi there i am working on LinkedList project with Java and i have some unclear issues in my mind. for example this is my "Patient" class;

```
public class Patient {

private int id;
private String name;
private String lastName;
private String doctor;

private Patient next;
private Patient prev;

public Patient(int id, String name, String lastName, String doctor, Patient next, Patient prev){

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.doctor = doctor;
    this.next = next;
    this.prev = prev;

}
```

and when i construct my LinkedList i create a header and tail node like this.

```
private Patient header = new Patient(0, null, null, null, null, null);
private Patient tail = new Patient(0, null, null ,null ,null, null);
```

but if i create these two nodes without `new Patient(0, null, null, null, null, null);` anything doesnt change. could you please explain why_?

Comment: what do you mean by "create nodes without new"?  What exactly do you do?  And what doesn't change?

Comment: i mean if i use just "private Patient header;" programme works same_?.

Comment: do I need to beg you to explain yourself completely?  Anyways, if you just write private Patient header; you declare a reference to an object of type Patient which for now points to null.  If you never assign it to anything but never try to dereference it (use it, such as invoke its instance methods) your program will "work".

Comment: well this is very clear answer :D thank you.

Comment: @quartaela: you're lucky because your question is very confusing to many of us.

Comment: well i realized that and apologize for my english. but at least if you can edit or give an correct example of how to ask this question again than it will be beneficial for me _? so i will ask my next question more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get null references when not using the new keyword. Have you tried to access and do something with Objects that aren't instanced with the new key word? 
Add a method called getName() and call it on a Patient variable before it is instanced. This will result in an "null pointer exception"

Comment: yes i get nullpointerexception. now i get it. thank you very much :)